# Callback functions of JavaScript doesn't work for the Like button click

Tags: javascript, facebook

[Function Summary]
The screen is redisplayed  by Callback function of JavaScript when click the LIKE button.

[Symptom]
Acess sites displayed the Like button using the HTTPS protocol.
Click The Like button, then Comment column displays at div tag and processing stops.

We expected below results.
When the Like button is clicked,
the information are asynchronously transmitted to Facebook site  and Callback functions of JavaScript are called 
and then each processing are executed.

Callback function : FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) { -- each processing --})

[Question]
Error Message "407 Proxy Authentication Required" displays when we access following page.

https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php 
(xd_arbiter.php)

I consider this error caused by follwing reasons.
 - The information is not returned from 'xd_arbiter.php.' 
 - Proxy-Authorization is not granted.

Please let me know workaround for avoiding this error.

[Environment]
Protocol:https
Browser:ForeFox15.0.1
Application Server:WebSphere Application Server  7.0.0.11 
OS:Windows2003 Server

Comment: callbacks are always sketchy, maybe try with a delayed window.settimeout in the callback function, see what happens.

Comment: If your proxy does not grant you access token the Facebook URL, then ask your proxy admin to fix this.